# Why is my Sound not Played?

Tags: iphone, ios6, avaudioplayer, avplayer

I was trying a lot to get this to work.
I try to explain. I have a sounds like that:

[See here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B39VLJYVNyVgcnF5cWRVT0llOXc/edit?usp=sharing)

I play sound from everywhere of my code by using:

```
[PlaySounds PlaySound:glo_sound_login];
```

this will this part of code

```
+(void)PlaySound:(NSString *)PlaySound{
    SystemSoundID soundID;
NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle
                        mainBundle]pathForResource:PlaySound ofType:@"mp3"];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL
                                            fileURLWithPath:soundFile],&soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
if (glo_pref_vibrate == YES) {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);}}
```

So my glo_sound_login looks like that:`NSString *glo_sound_login=@"Login";`

This is working just fine. But when I try to call

```
[PlaySounds PlaySound:glo_sound_update];
```

which looks like that:`NSString *glo_sound_update=@"Update";`

Then it wont play my update sound!
Is there an explanation why I wont play my sound?
For any Kind of help I am thankful!! :)
Thank you
One more thing:
When I try to klick on the Update.mp3 file xcode opens the file and it will play:
[See Here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B39VLJYVNyVgeWg1WDJPLTd3alk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: share more code to get an good answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation about AudioServicesPlaySystemSound function, you cannot use a mp3 format in that context.

Full documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesPlaySystemSound)

> Sound files that you play using this function must be:
>
> - No longer than 30 seconds in duration
> - In linear PCM or IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM) format
> - Packaged in a .caf, .aif, or .wav file

Notice: use afconvert to easily create right format files.

example to generate a CAF file / little-endian 16bit (should be perfect).

```
/usr/bin/afconvert -f caff -d LEI16 {INPUT} {OUTPUT}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I am still confused, because some of the files are played correctly!
what is my alternative?

Comment: Another important thing, only one file at a time can be played using that way.

Comment: I understand it can be confusing but I recommend to begin to try with the audio formats listed and after try other ones like mp3. Notice that there is a way to play mp3 (recommended for longer tracks actually). For short sound mp3 is not suitable. How long are your sounds ?

Comment: then I confirm that it is better to avoid the mp3 in that case. Have you tried ?